# How do I tell Drupal not to aggregate my css file

Tags: 7, theming, css-js-aggregation

I have enabled Drupal's *Aggregate and compress CSS files*. What should I do in order to exclude certain css files from being aggregated and compressed?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you mention what would be it good for? I'm curious.

Comment: I have a css file that changes per node and dont want it to be a part of the large css.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To stop a file being aggregated, you can add a flag to the [drupal_add_css()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7) command which loads the file. To do this, hunt where the CSS is added and add `array('preprocess' => FALSE)` after the style, e.g.

```
drupal_add_css('/fonts/fonts-min.css', array('preprocess' => FALSE));
```

Alternatively, external CSS are never compressed, so if you change the CSS to the absolute URL of the file it won't be compressed.

```
drupal_add_css('http://mysite/css/fonts-min.css');
```

If you want to change a CSS included from a .info file, it might be best to add it as an external file with `_preprocess_html` in template.php. This is well explained under 'Adding external stylesheets' on [this page](http://drupal.org/node/171209).

Comment: hey, thanks, you are right, but isn't it supposed to be ```array('preprocess' => FALSE));```? that's what the doc says.

Comment: Oopse, correct, my bad. Copied it out of the defaults so I wouldn't get the spelling wrong :-/

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, but instead of using drupal_add_css I attached my files to a page like this:

```
function module_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['some_element']['#attached'] = array(
    'css' => array(
      'path/to/css/style.css',
    )
  )
}
```

While digging in the [attached core code](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_process_attached/7) I found that we can use John C's solution here too like this:

```
function module_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['some_element']['#attached'] = array(
    'css' => array(
      'path/to/css/style.css' => array(
        'preprocess' => FALSE,
      )
    )
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How I did this really dirty on Drupal 8 since it's still in dev and too much is changing now:

**THEMENAME.theme** file:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $variables['css_address'] = drupal_get_path('theme', 'themename') . '/cssfile.css';
}
```

And added something like this to head tag in **html.html.twig** template file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ css_address }}">
```

There's going to be a better way soon.